# Setting OnPush as default for all applications in nrwl-nx

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

Is there a way to have all components generated with OnPush?

Similar to: `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.changeDetection OnPush`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the solutions to my question :)

just add

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss",
      "changeDetection": "OnPush"
 }
```

to yor `workspace.json` file at the very end of `"schematics": {}` :)

Answer (score 3):

Inside `nx.json`, do the following:

```
"@nrwl/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss",
      "changeDetection": "OnPush" // add this
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like Duda said, But instead of @nrwl change it to @nx

```
"@nx/angular:component": {
  "style": "scss",
  "changeDetection": "OnPush"
}
```